# Set WORKING_DIRECTORY for ExternalProject_Add CONFIGURE_COMMAND

Tags: cmake, external-project

I'm trying to add an Automake project as an external project.
The Automake configure script (usually run with `./configure`) contains a relative path to a resource file. The file is found when I run configure manually, because my working directory is in the source directory. However, when I run `configure` with the `ExternalProject_Add`, it can't find the resource file because the working directory is `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR`.

```
ExternalProject_Add(zlib
        SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND sh ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/configure
        BUILD_COMMAND make)
```

How can I set the working directory for the configuration step so that the config script finds the required files?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In `ExternalProject_Add` configuration step is performed with build directory (*BINARY_DIR* option) being current, so you may set this option:

```
ExternalProject_Add(...
    BINARY_DIR <dir>
    ...
)
```

For in-source builds (when build directory is the same as source directory), *BUILD_IN_SOURCE* option could be used as alternative to set *BINARY_DIR* option:

```
ExternalProject_Add(...
    BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
    ...
)
```

More info see at [ExternalProject documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/module/ExternalProject.html) page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Tsyvarev. I ended up using the `BUILD_IN_SOURCE` option. I was expecting the files to be copied into the build directory, instead of a subdirectory.